# Calling Method In a fragment from Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have five `Fragments` attached to a `ViewPager`. I want to validate forms in each before sending the data to my server. So, I decided to loop through the `Fragments` to see if I can reach the methods. But, I know it can't be reached like that. Below is what I tried

```
 Fragment[] listOfFrags = {new Frag1(), new Frag2(), new Frag3(), new Frag4(),
            new ExpenseFragment()};
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFrags.length; i++) {
        Fragment cuurentFrag = listOfFrags[i];
        boolean checker = cuurentFrag.ValidateData();<-- The unreachable destination
    }
```

And this is my `Adapter`

```
    public PagersAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new Frag1();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Frag1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Frag2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Frag3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Frag4();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Frag5();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: Is the data in each fragment independent or dependent somehow on the previous fragment?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: One thing I made sure is that, there names are the same and return a Boolean value

Comment: @Blackbelt as I've said. I've EditTexts in each Fragment. I need to validate each and every fragment one after another and store the data to SharedPref. The handling is within the Fragments. I am just returning a Boolean value from the methods to be able to point the user to the right screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you mean is to call the `ValidateData()` method of each fragment. You can write a super class extending `Fragment` which contains the `ValidateData()` method and make all your other fragments extend the super class. When you want to call the `ValidateData()` method, just cast your fragments to the super class. And I guess there're also some other problems in your code.

Comment: Hey, I did that  `boolean toCheck = (AppControllerFragment(Fragment1)).validate1();` but, I keep getting Method Call Expected

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use your adapter to store a list of its Fragments as per the sample below.

```
   private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment0;
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment1;
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment2;
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

public SparseArray<Fragment> getRegisteredFragments(){
    return registeredFragments;
    }
}
```

As ProtossShuttle said you could create a superclass (or interface depending on your needs) with a validate method which you can call on each Fragment by iterating through this list.